# How can I get an article's: author, the date it was uploaded and updated?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This is my function that scrapes articles and right now I'm trying to work on how I can scrape the author's name, the date it was uploaded, and the date it was updated. What are some approaches I can take that would work on numerous articles on the SF chronicle?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
# Initializing our title key
title_key = 'title'
dictionary.setdefault(title_key, [])

# Initializing our url key
url_key = 'url'
dictionary.setdefault(url_key, [])

# Initializing our author key
author_key = 'author'
dictionary.setdefault(text_key, [])

# Initializing our date key
author_key = 'date'
dictionary.setdefault(text_key, [])

# Initializing our date updated key
author_key = 'date_updated'
dictionary.setdefault(text_key, []) 

def article_scraper(url):
    # Opening up the connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    # HTML parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    dictionary['url'].append(url)
    dictionary['title'].append(page_soup.title.string)
    dictionary['author'] = page_soup.select("author.name")
    return(dictionary)

articles[0] = 'https://www.sfchronicle.com/news/bayarea/heatherknight/article/Special-education-teacher-a-prime-example-of-13560483.php'
article0 = article_scraper(articles[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For author's name:

```
author = soup.findAll("div", {"class": ""header-authors-name"})
```